# Oracle Apex Button not sending values the first time

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a button that sends out two Item values (items with an actual value. I can confirm they are not null because there are regions on the same page using them as substitution strings), when I click on it the following happens:

- First time on session I click it: it doesn't set the value items on the new page
- If I go back and click the same button again: it sets the required values on the new page

(no cache clearing processes are in place.
Pic 1: button configuration
Pic 2: result when clicked the first time
Pic 3: result when clicked a second time after going back to the previous page and clicking it again)

[image: button actions]
[image: result first click]
[image: result second click after going back to the previous page and clicking again]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be sent if they are in session (server side), for this you need to submit them (or the page) before the link.

So make sure the button submits, and create a **branch** in **processing** with the same link builder you have in the image.

And dont forget to select your button that submits here: **Server-side Condition** => **When Button Pressed**

Comment: Thank you! I created one under 'processing' with the same targets (same items) and....it had the same result as before unfortunately. Changed the button to submit page as well (so the branch would be the only one pulling-sending the values) but it didn't work. 
Not sure what's happening here....

Comment: Fixed it, had to add a couple of items mimicking the source ones receiving the same info....and this time it worked. I think it was like you said, weren't being stored in session maybe cause of the sequence? not sure...but thank you!